# How to register a Renderer with CRaSH

Tags: spring-boot

After reading about the remote shell in the Spring Boot documentation I started playing around with it. I implemented a new `Command` that produces a Stream of one of my database entities called company.
This works fine. So I want to output my stream of companies in the console. This is done by calling `toString()` by default. While this seams reasonable there is also a way to get nicer results by using a Renderer.

Implementing one should be straight forward as I can delegate most of the work to one of the already existing ones. I use `MapRenderer`.

```
class CompanyRenderer extends Renderer<Company> {

    private final mapRenderer = new MapRenderer()

    @Override Class<Company> getType() { Company }

    @Override LineRenderer renderer(Iterator<Company> stream) {
        def list = []
        stream.forEachRemaining({
            list.add([id: it.id, name: it.name])
        })

        return mapRenderer.renderer(list.iterator())
    }
}
```

As you can see I just take some fields from my entity put them into a `Map`and then delegate to a instance of `MapRenderer` to do the real work.

#### TL;DR

Only problem is: How do I register my `Renderer` with CRaSH?

#### Links

- Spring Boot documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-remote-shell.html
- CRaSH documentation (not helping) http://www.crashub.org/1.3/reference.html#_renderers

Comment: Looks like they use the Java ServiceLoader (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) to load the renderers... not sure what you need to do to add a custom one, but maybe this will help you figure it out.